# How to change the value in laravel 5 collection

Tags: php, laravel, collections, laravel-5

I have some problems here.
I get a collection which like:

```
$VenderData=Vender::where('active', '=', '1')->get();
```

Inside the collection i have a column called '**type**' and the data looks like `'A1,A2,A3,'`
  or
`'A1,A3,'` 
I want to transfer those codes to real names from 
another table '**vender_type**'.

```
code name
 A1    XX
 A2    OO
 A3    ZZ
```

then add a new column into the original collection $VenderData.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must split the type attribute (using `array explode(string $delimiter , string $string)`) , and get the name of each one from `vender_type` table, try this :

```
$VenderData = Vender::where('active', '=', '1')->get();
foreach($VenderData as $vend)
{
     $vend->new_type = array();
     $types = explode(",", $vend->type);
     foreach($types as $type)
     { 
         $t = vender_type::where('code', $type)->first();
         if($t)
             $vend->name_type[] = $t->name;
             // or for example : $vend->name_type[$type] = $t->name;
     }
}
```

I hope that will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need better query than modifying each value after. This `vender_type` is probably some foreign key in you database so you can get that value in query builder. To find out about foreign keys and joins in laravel eloquent check [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#joins).

Basically you need something like this

```
$users = DB::table('table1')
        ->join('table2', 'table1.vender_type', '=', 'table2.vender_type')
        ->select('table1.code', 'table1.name', 'table2.vender_type')
        ->where('table1.active', '=', '1')
        ->get();
```

Just replace `table1` and `table2` with values of you table names in database and you're done.

Hope it helps